# Does HashMatch join use temp tables for both datasets in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am executing the following query in AdventureWorks2014 DB.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON

SELECT 
    e.JobTitle,
    a.City,
    p.LastName + ', ' + p.FirstName AS EmployeeName
FROM 
    HumanResources.Employee AS e
JOIN 
    Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS bea ON e.BusinessEntityID = bea.BusinessEntityID
JOIN 
    Person.Address a ON bea.AddressID = a.AddressID
JOIN 
    Person.Person AS p ON e.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID ;

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

It generates an execution plan which contains a Hash Match (Inner Join) of an Output of an Nested Join (say output 1, 290 rows) and an output of Index Scan of Address table (say output 2, 19614 rows).

When a Hash Match (Inner Join) Occurs, does it create Temp Tables (#tables) for both Output 1 and Output 2 or just Output 1 ?

If the answer is just 'Output 1', then why doesn't it creates a data structure 'In Memory' for the smaller output instead of creating a physical tables which requires file storage ?

Comment: It creates a hash table  by computing a hash value for each row from its build input. It asks for a memory grant for this operation. If the value is estimated right and it gets required memory it performs all operations 'In Memory'. If it got less memory than it needed it uses tempdb.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin - My understanding is that it creates temp (hash) tables in tempdb for sure, question is does it do it for both the outputs or just one of them ? If one of them (the smaller one), why cant it do it 'In Memory' ? Why wouldn't the sql server grant memory even under no load (like I ran under no load at all) ?

Comment: It might... it might not. It does the best it can. The concept of hash and memory usage are unrelated things. _Why wouldn't the sql server grant memory even under no load_ I don't know. Do you think it isn't?

Comment: @Gsab, a hash table is not in tempdb for sure. It spills to tempdb only if more rows are returned than estimated like Denis said. The spills are logged in the default trace.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

> When a Hash Match (Inner Join) Occurs, does it create Temp Tables (#tables) for both Output 1 and Output 2 or just Output 1 ?

(*in short) SQL Server uses the statistics in order to choose the smaller table of the two inputs, and will create hash table for this table. This is why we call this table a "build input". This is the one on top in the execution plan. SQL Server tries to create the table in memory first but if there is no place then it will use physical disk space in TEMPDB.

Next SQL Server gets the data from the larger table(named "probe input"), compares it to the hash table using the hash match function, and return any matched rows.